# Installing version 16 of the Android SDK tools

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-tools, android-build

I'm trying to build a project in Android Studio that targets API16 (Android version 4.1.2).  Using the SDK manager I was able to download that SDK platform but an exception is raised at compile-time as it's trying to parse a compiled `.jar` file:

```
bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
```

My understanding of this issue is that I need the build tools to match the API version I'm targeting (since I currently only have the most recent version of the build tools).  However, I am unable to install them because they're unavailable in both the SDK manager and on the Android website (http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html).  Is there another way to install this version of the build tools?  (Alternatively, if installing that version of the build tools is unnecessary, how do I resolve this issue?)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the Java version (i.e. the version the jar, or rather the class files inside it, was compiled with). It actually has nothing to do with the *Android* version.

`0x34` means the jar was compiled with Java 8 (see the list of possible values [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout)). Android can only use jars compiled as Java 6.

If you have the sources for this library, you should recompile it again with the `-target 1.6` flag.